# Transmission-Daemon not working (Debian 8 / OpenVZ) UDP Issue

Tags: debian, daemon, udp, transmission

I'm trying to install transmission on my VPS (under OpenVZ) to download torrents on it.
When running something like:

```
transmission-cli example.torrent
```

It'll print:

```
transmission-cli 2.84 (14307)
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.477 EDT] Transmission 2.84 (14307) started
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.495 EDT] RPC Server: Adding address to whitelist: 127.0.0.1
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.496 EDT] UDP: Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 266240
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.496 EDT] UDP: Please add the line "net.core.rmem_max = 4194304" to /etc/sysctl.conf
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.496 EDT] UDP: Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 266240
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.496 EDT] UDP: Please add the line "net.core.wmem_max = 1048576" to /etc/sysctl.conf
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.496 EDT] DHT: Generating new id
[2017-10-17 18:25:23.548 EDT] Saved "/root/.config/transmission/torrents/example.torrent"
[2017-10-17 18:25:25.825 EDT] Port Forwarding: State changed from "Not forwarded" to "???"
Progress: 0.0%, dl fro[2017-10-17 18:25:28.995 EDT] Changed open file limit from 65536 to 1024
Progress: 0.0%, [1]    7657 killed     transmission-cli example.torrent
```

It just gets killed.
I made a lot of research, tried to modify in sysctl.conf the rmem and wmem max fields but it's permission denied because of OpenVZ.
So how to deal with that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is there enough RAM memory for the `transmission-cli` process?

Run `free` or `top` to see how much memory is occupied.